# Intel Smart Response with mSATA SSD vs OS installed on mSATA SSD

Tags: dell-xps, msata

I have Dell XPS 15 L501X laptop which has recently diagnosed with malfunctioning mSATA SSD. Dell support suggested me to replace this drive. I am planning to replace it with 128GB or 256GB SSD and have OS installed on it.

I have read about “Intel Smart Response Technology” makes use of this mSATA.

I am not sure how OS installed on regular SATA hard drive + “Intel Smart Response Technology” scale against OS installed on mSATA SSD.

Can someone help me decide whether I should go ahead replace mSATA with bigger capacity and use it for OS installation.